# load controller function in block and from block to .phtml

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

controller viewaction . i have used below function in **indexController**

```
 public function viewAction($string){
 $stro  = $this->getRequest()->getParams('key');
 if($stro != null){
  $model = Mage::getModel('finder/finder');
 $collection = $model->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('companyname', $stro);

 $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
  }
 $this->loadLayout();
  $this->renderLayout();
```

in front end layout fiel finder.xml i have called follwing code;

```
 <finder_index_view>
 <reference name="content">
<block type="finder/info"  name="finder" template="finder/info.phtml" />
 </reference>
 </finder_index_view>
```

how to display output of this controller function in info.phtml file.?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Controller (IndexController.php) file In index controller simply load the layout and render it.

```
<?php
class Abc_Example_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

Step 2: Layout (custom.xml) file Put the under given code in the layout file of module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <example_index_index>
       <reference name="content">
           <block type="example/collection" name="collection" template="example/collection.phtml" />
       </reference>
   </example_index_index>
</layout>
```

here is code for block where you can define collection

```
 <?php
    class Abc_Example_Block_Collection extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $stro  = $this->getRequest()->getParams('key');
            if($stro != null){
            $model = Mage::getModel('finder/finder');
            $collection = $model->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('companyname', $stro);
            $this->setCollection($collection);
        }
   }
```

and now you can access this collection in info.phtml

```
<?php $collection = $this->getCollection(); ?>
```

hope this will help you